# Problem animating rigid bodies

Tags: animation

I have an animation and in one part I would like a pencil to roll and fall off a table.  The pencil is an active object and the table top is a passive object.  I have set key frames for the start position of the pencil and also enabled Dynamic and Animated in the Rigid body settings.  I have then set the end position of the pencil just before it would roll off the table and disabled Animated in the rigid body settings.  Starting from frame zero this works fine.  However, if I try to use this set up further down the timeline the pencil disappears at the end of the animated phase. Any help appreciated (2.91).

Comment: show us your blend file

Comment: try to disable rigid body temporarily. and key the pencil position in the same frame you keyed the Animated = off. If it needs some force on the simulation start just use animated part of timeline to give the pencil right speed and direction.

Comment: Also, check your rigid body cache size. It must be big enough to cover the entire animation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Specifying the cache and baking the simulation did the trick. I wasn't aware of these settings in Scene Properties been a great help. Thanks